# How to get a cookie on a client component and still work with SSR? (NextJS 13, App routing)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How can I get a cookie from a client component during SSR?

page.tsx

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  const myCookie = cookies().get("myCookie"); // Works as expected (on the server)

  return <ClientComponent />;
}
```

clientComponent.tsx

```
"use client";

export default function ClientComponent() {

  const myCookie = ???;

  return <>{myCookie}</>; 
}
```

- Can't `import { cookies } from "next/headers";` from a client component.
- Can't use `document.cookie` during SSR.
- The npm library `cookies-next` doesn't throw an error during SSR but it doesn't return the cookie, so on the client there's the error "Hydration failed". During SSR it doesn't have the request object.

I know I can pass the cookie from the server component to the client component and their children via props like a hot potato but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: You could use `document.cookie` but call it in a `useEffect` if the cookie is not marked server only.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar - It doesn't work with SSR. The component flashes without the cookie data and then updates.

Comment: Just show some loader untile the useEffect runs.

Comment: You could use a package like [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) to access the cookie on the client side.

Comment: @FabioNettis - It uses `document.cookie`